# titlesec --- hanging indent in titleformat?

Tags: titlesec

What I want:

```
1.1    _Section Body_   Each section has only a single paragraph, which
       displays like it and the section title is a single paragraph.
       This "single paragraph" (so to speak) has a hanging indent, such
       that the 2nd line onwards is flushed with Section Body.
```

I use the word `runin` in reference to `titleformat`'s shape.

I managed to get `\thesection` bolded correctly, the section body underlined, and the paragraph following to runin.

But I can't seem to style the paragraph at all. `\parindent` and `\leftskip` don't work at all.

Here's my attempt:

```
\titleformat{\section}[runin]
  {\normalfont\scshape\bfseries}
  {\makebox[2em]{\thesection}}
  {5pt}
  {\underline{#1}}
  [\setlength{\leftskip}{-20pt}
   \setlength{\parskip}{20pt}]
```

Update:

I gave up on `titlesec`. I'm using KOMA script, so I may be facing some problems from compatibility.

Here's my new code:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  afterskip=-10pt
]{section}
```

I managed to get that `runin` shape (where my section content is in same paragraph as my section title/body). But I still can't get the hanging indent.

**Is there no documentation at all for `RedeclareSectionCommand`?**

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What you want is not clear. What should be hanging?  All the text in the section?

Comment: `titlesec` and KOMA are not compatible with each other.

Comment: @AlanMunn Which is why I reverted to `RedeclareSectionCommand`. How do I get this to work with that?